# What's our position on leaked material that was obtained illegally?

Tags: discussion, legal

Some leaks can from accidental statements by actors, or the like. I'm not talking about that.

I'm think of blackhat leaks, which can be illegal.

**Do we allow such leaks on the site?**

Comment: I clarified the title, because I think "unofficial" can include material that isn't illegal: for example, a fan photo from the set of a film. (IANAL, I'm assuming that's legal.) Feel free to rollback and/or clarify the question if you disagree.

Comment: Related, possible dupe: [Should We Allow Links to Sources of a Questionable Legal Status?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1349/5184) - just kind of depends on what exactly we're talking about here - links, or re-hosting, or what.

Comment: Also see: [Can images added to SFF content **without attribution** violate copyright?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1849/5184) for a question on rehosted content.

Comment: I assume this is in regards to something like the Sony hack?

Comment: @Omegacron: That was my assumption.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Stack Exchange [Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal) expressly forbid using the service for illegal activity. These two sentences seem particularly relevant:

> Any fraudulent, abusive, or otherwise illegal activity or any use of the Services or Content in violation of this Agreement may be grounds for termination of Subscriber’s right to Services or to access the Network. [...]
>
> Use of the Network or Services to violate the security of any computer network, crack passwords or security encryption codes, **transfer or store illegal material** including that are deemed threatening or obscene, or engage in any kind of illegal activity is expressly prohibited.

I imagine reposting material that was obtaining illegally falls squarely under that second sentence. Don't do it.

If you see illegal material, then please edit to remove it. If the OP has a pattern of posting illegal content, or it should be obvious that it was illegal, then flag for moderator attention with the custom flag reason. Explain why you think the content was obtained illegally – they can decide what to do next, and escalate it to SE Staff as necessary.

---

**ETA, after 12 hours reflection:** When I wrote the hard-lined response above, I was thinking in very black-and-white terms. I am not a lawyer. The OP’s use of the word “blackhat” made me think of things that any reasonable person would find nefarious or illegal.

For example: there’s a grey area (that we tend to let slide) with respect to quoting scripts for released films that are posted online, even though they probably aren’t there with the writer’s permission. But there’s a difference between that and, say, hacking into Joss Whedon’s voicemail to get the latest Avengers rumours.

I am not a lawyer. Legal stuff is hard.

Comment: One thing to consider, particularly when discussing what tolerance we have, if any: copyright violations, no matter how innocuous are still technically illegal. For example, many sites which host shooting/draft scripts do so without permission. Do we wish to not allow links to such things? What about links to Youtube videos posted without permission?

Comment: @phantom42 Yeah, there are lots of grey areas. (This is why I'm not a lawyer.) The term “blackhat” in the question made me think of very black-and-white stuff, eg using production materials from the Sony hacking. I don't have a good definition except "I'll know it when I see it". :-/

Comment: It's not down to users (for the most part) to police external sites. Youtube videos are, by definition, part of the purview of youtube, even if linked here.

Comment: We're not responsible for other sites hosting illegal content either - but that doesn't necessarily make it ok to link to them.

Comment: @phantom42 - Yes, which is why I'm inclined to err on the side of allowing content unless there's a damned good reason not to.

Comment: @Richard I wonder where those Doctor Who leaked transcripts fall... ;-)

Comment: @randal'thor - For the record, they weren't leaked. The BBC accidentally made them publicly available, then regretted it.

Answer (score 7):

I think that there would be no problem discussing it, but you should probably avoid posting anything substantive of the material itself. As mentioned by alexwlchan, it's still copyrighted material, so we could at best post excerpts or low-quality images, and only for constructive discussion.