# Should we authorize question/answer about leaked content

Tags: discussion

With the recent HBO hack and subsequent leaks, I think the question should be asked.

**What is the policy to adopt toward question/answer based on leaked material ?**

Several ways to see this problem can arise. To list a few legality, spoil exposition on this site, future changes between the leaked version and the definitive version. And I am certain that I am missing a lot in this problem.

EDIT : I am not talking about the problem of referencing illegal content, but can we base a question/answer on a leaked content, even without any direct link to this content ?

Comment: Related, possible dupe: [What's our position on leaked material that was obtained illegally?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6693/5184) and [Should We Allow Links to Sources of a Questionable Legal Status?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1349/5184)

Comment: For me the answers to this questions is more pointed at "In no way should we use this platform to promote illegal content", the question is here more : "Can we use illegal content as a basis of answer" without including links. I update the question to be clearer

Comment: I know, and that's why I didn't VTC, but [fuzzyboot's answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6696/5184) does touch on that - suggesting that we be allowed to discuss it, but not link to it.

Comment: In this *particular* case, why not simply close under the “future works” policy? Strictly speaking, this *is* a question about something that hasn’t been released yet. It could be closed now and reopened in a few days when the episode proper comes out.

Comment: re: the spoiler policy specifically, I consider leaked content "unreleased" as far as spoilers go and will be very cross if I'm spoiled by it.

Comment: Some people get access to pre-screenings, and some countries or timezones get content released first. We don't bring in future works or any other policy regarding closing questions just because someone else has seen the content before the greater audience has. I would remove the "legal" aspect from consideration here and do what we normally do: Upvote or downvote based on whether or not it's a good answer. And, FWIW, a great many of our answers are based on content only a few of users have immediate access to. We generally trust if someone says they've seen/read the content.

Comment: No, because it's not nice, because basically, what you'd be doing is limiting the question to only those who have seen't the leaked material.

Comment: Beware: the next episode of GoT has leaked due to HBO Spain and/or Nordic blundering.